# Kohana 3.3 relationships work locally but not on server

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I just moved my website from localhost to real host.... and the problems began.

On my windows machine the relationships work, but on my host kohana throws `Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The klinikas property does not exist in the Model_User class`

My Model_User class contains these relations

```
protected $_has_many = array(
       'klinikas' => array('model'=>'klinika','through'=>'klinikas_users'),
       'roles' => array('model' => 'role', 'through' => 'roles_users'),
);
```

The question is what couses this and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out i just needed to upercase my module name from `user.php` to `User.php` and wiola it works!